# When i develop my codes under Sun JDK and run my codes in Oracle JRockit JVM, am i using libraries from JRockit?

Tags: java

When i develop my codes under Sun Standard JDK, and run my codes in Oracle JRockit JVM, am i using the implementation of the `String` class provided by Hotspot VM or JRockit VM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "when you develop your code", but I assume that you are referring to the JRE configuration in your IDE when you are doing your development.

Either way, the important thing to know is that when you run your code, the VM is providing the implementation for the classes that your code does not include.  So if you are using a java String class, it will be the VM that is providing it.  If you are running the code in your IDE, then it would be Sun's implementation.  If you are running it in a different VM, it would be that VM that is providing the implementations.

So, long answer to say that it would be the JRockit String implementation.

Answer (score 1):

It will be JRockit JVM while runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the JRockit String implementation is fully Java complaint, so API wise there are no differences. JRockit substitutes some parts of the core classes for efficiency, but no public APIs are changed.